# Is php://output is same for the lifcycle of a request?

Tags: php

I want to understand how writing to `php://output` work.

When a web server receives a request it is forwarded to a PHP process. Is this process has unique buffer `php://output` which means when I open/write to this stream multiple time, I'm writing to the same location for the current request?

Comment: The lifecycle lasts until you 1) break the connection, 2) run into a timeout, 3) server crashes, 4) the PHP process ends or crashed via Error/Exception.

Comment: Every request has its own buffer.

Comment: Thank you Markus for your reponse.  if i understand when i use echo, print, function s ob_*,  the output go to the same buffer (php://output) ?

Comment: Yes.  Are you seeing an error, or problem that needs to be solved?  Please clarify

Comment: @JozephB. Correct. Each request has its own buffer. So if you have two requests in parallel they are each isolated and you can not output into the others. All your output goes to a buffer first. It is flushed on buffer full event or by process end of life or manual flush.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The behavior of `echo`, `print` and `fwrite(php://output)` are the same, this means that they share the same output target and that target can be changed (by calling `ob_*` functions or setting `output_handler`), e.g.

```
$f = fopen('php://output', '');
fwrite($f, 'a');
ob_start();
fwrite($f, 'b');
ob_clean();
```

If you run the above code, you can only see `a` is output.

BTW, the original output target is `stdout`, but you cannot directly access it in the CGI mode. Requests processed by the same process will use this pipe, but Zend guarantees that it will flush the pipe at the end of the request.

Comment: When i use ob_start before writing to php://output  and at the end i call ob_clean it clean what i write to php://output :  $out = \fopen('php://output', 'w');
fwrite($out, 'One');
fclose($out);

ob_start();
echo 'test';
echo('\r');
ob_end_clean();

// display One

ob_start();
$out = \fopen('php://output', 'w');
fwrite($out, 'One');
fclose($out);

echo 'test';
echo('\r');
ob_end_clean();

// display nothing

Comment: @JozephB. Is there a problem?